# remove duplicates based on the value of another column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following file:

```
AA,true
AA,false
BB,false
CC,false
BB,true
DD,true
```

I am trying to look for duplicates and remove the line that has the column value equals to `true`.

as output it should be:

```
AA,false
BB,false
CC,false
DD,true
```

Comment: So.. only keep `true` if it's the first instance of the first column?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Probably because is a uniq entry and is printed "as it is"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest because DD,true is not a duplicate we don't have another line with DD,false.

Comment: `AA,true
AA,false
AA,false
AA,false`
What output should be in this case? I understand, that row should be removed only if it is having duplicate and contain `true` at the same time. All `false` rows should be stay untouched in any case. That is, in this case, only `AA, true` will be removed. But all answers leaves only one line - `AA,false`. Just interesting :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk -F, '$2 == "false" {data[$1]=$2 } $2=="true" { if ( data[$1]!="false" ) { data[$1]=$2 } } END { OFS=","; for (item in data) { print item,data[item] }}' input
```

To expand the script vertically for explanation:

```
BEGIN {
   FS=","         # Set the input separator; this is what -F, does.
}
$2 == "false" {    # For any line whose second field is "false", we
   data[$1]=$2     # will use that value no matter what.
}
$2=="true" {                    # For lines whose second field is "true",
   if ( data[$1]!="false" ) {   # only keep if if we haven't yet seen a
      data[$1]=$2               # "false"
   }
}
END {                           # Now that we have tabulated our data, we
   OFS=","                      # can print it out by iterating through 
   for (item in data) {         # the array we created.
      print item,data[item]
   }
}
```

Comment: @DopeGhoti well explained! You've got my +1 on this.

Answer (score 14):

Simple version:

```
sort input.txt | awk -F, '!a[$1]++'
```

"false" sorts alphabetically before "true," and the Awk command here just keeps the first row only for each distinct first field value.

If you want to keep "true" instead of "false," reverse sort it, pass it to the same Awk command, and reverse sort it again afterward.

Comment: also, if `-u` option is available, `sort input.txt | sort -t, -u -k1,1`

Comment: @Sundeep why use two `sort` calls? Why not just `sort -ut, -k1,1 input.txt `?

Comment: @terdon because `-u` will retain the first line found from input file among duplicates... for given case, input has to be sorted before `-u` can be applied... for ex: `AA,true` will be printed instead of `AA,false` since it appears first in given sample.. same reason why `awk -F, '!a[$1]++'` alone won't solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -F, -lane '
   exists $h{$F[0]} or $h[$h{$F[0]}=@h]=$_;
   $h=$_; /,false$/ or $_=$h for $h[$h{$F[0]}];
   END{ print for @h; }
' duplicates.file
```

---

Data structures:

- Hash `%h` whose keys are first fields (AAA, BBB, CCC, etc.) and corresponding values are numbers telling the order in which the keys were encountered. Thus, e.g., key AAA => 0, key BBB => 1, key CCC => 2.
- Array `@h` whose elements are lines contained in the order of printing. So if both true and false are found in data, then the false value will go into the array. OTW, if there's one type of data, then that would be present.

Another way is using GNU sed:

```
sed -Ee '
   G
   /^([^,]*),(false|true)\n(.*\n)?\1,\2(\n|$)/ba
   /^([^,]*)(,true)\n(.*\n)?\1,false(\n|$)/ba
   /^([^,]*)(,false)\n((.*\n)?)\1,true(\n|$)/{
      s//\3\1\2\5/;h;ba
   }
   s/([^\n]*)\n(.*)$/\2\n\1/;s/^\n*//
   h;:a;$!d;g
' duplicates.file
```

FWIW, the POSIX equivalent code for the above GNU-sed code is listed below:

```
sed -e '
   G

   /^\([^,]*\),\(false\)\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\1,\2$/ba
   /^\([^,]*\),\(false\)\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\1,\2\n/ba

   /^\([^,]*\),\(true\)\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\1,\2$/ba
   /^\([^,]*\),\(true\)\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\1,\2\n/ba

   /^\([^,]*\),true\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\1,false$/ba
   /^\([^,]*\),true\n\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\1,false\n/ba

   /^\([^,]*\)\(,false\)\n\(\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\)\1,true$/{
      s//\3\1\2/
      h
      ba
   }
   /^\([^,]*\)\(,false\)\n\(\(.*\n\)\{0,1\}\)\1,true\n/{
      s//\3\1\2\n/
      h
      ba
   }

   y/\n_/_\n/
   s/\([^_]*\)_\(.*\)$/\2_\1/;s/^_*//
   y/\n_/_\n/

   h;:a;$!d;g
' duplicates.file
```

---

## Explanation

- In this method we store the result to be finally printed in the hold space.
- For every line read, we append the hold space to the pattern space for examination of the current line vis-a-vis the existing state of the hold space.
- Now 5 things can possibly happen during this comparison:

  - a) Current line matches somewhere in the hold line & false:false.

    - [ACTION] Since same false state is found, then do nothing.
  - b) Current line matches somewhere in the hold line & true:true.

    - [ACTION] Since same true state is found, then do nothing.
  - c) Current line matches somewhere in the hold line & true:false.

    - [ACTION] Since a false state already exists, do nothing.
  - d) Current line matches somewhere in the hold line & false:true.

    - [ACTION] This involves some work, in that we need to replace the false line at the exact same position where the true is located.
  - e) Current line DOES NOT match anywhere in the hold line.

    - [ACTION] Move the present line to the end.

---

## Results

```
AA,false
BB,false
CC,false
DD,true
```

Answer (score 3):

For each input line, store the value of the second field in associative array `a` (using the first field as the array's key) **ONLY** if we haven't already stored the value `false` for that key.  Use `,` for both input and output field separator.  Print out the array after we've read all input lines.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'a[$1] != "false" { a[$1] = $2 };
                    END { for (i in a) {print i,a[i]} }' truefalse.txt
AA,false
BB,false
CC,false
DD,true
```

The significant difference between this and DopeGhoti's version is that this version doesn't care at all about the value of `$2`, it only cares about the value, if any, of `a[$1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Two-pass `sort` solution

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -t, file | sort -k1,1 -t, -u
```

First `sort` pass clusters records by field `1` with `false` records preceding `true` for each block of records sharing a common field `1` value. The second `sort` pass is set up to yield one record for each distinct value within field `1` courtesy the `-u`. Since `-u` implies stable sort, the one record thus yielded is the first record encountered for each distinct value within field `1` - which is a record with `false` in the second field due to the work done by the first `sort` pass